# Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used ggplot to make an error bar
first, i computed se.
the data name is "read"

```
> p = read %>%   filter(bookshelf == "read") %>%   group_by(month_read)
   > %>%   summarize(mean = mean(pages),sd=sd(pages), n=length(month_read),
   > se=sd(pages)/sqrt(n))
> attach(p)
```

these are the result.

```
      month_read    mean         sd         n      se
        (fctr)      (dbl)       (dbl)     (int)   (dbl)
1        April    294.9500    84.34171     20    18.85938
2       August    372.2857    195.90988    14    52.35912
3     December    472.5294    215.32769    17    52.22464
4     February    319.0000    87.74763     18    20.68232
5      January    305.0400    109.31090    25    21.86218
6         July    381.3333    190.55646    18    44.91459
7         June    333.9167    133.19320    24    27.18795
8        March    319.0625    138.68596    16    34.67149
9          May    351.2273    136.12212    22    29.02133
10    November    302.1667    67.57465     12    19.50712
11     October    388.4444    148.11323     9    49.37108
12   September    388.6250    125.57859     8    44.39874
```

and then i tried to make a ggplot

```
> ggplot(read, aes(x=month_read, y=pages), fill=pages) +   
> geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +  
> geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=mean+se, ymin=mean-se),
>                 width=.2,
>                 position=position_dodge(0.9))
```

However,I got this error

> Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the
>   dataProblems:mean + se, mean - se

========================================================================

what should i correct?

thanks.

Comment: Generally, attaching your data is not a good idea. And your issue is hard to replicate because 'pages' is missing. Does your error persist if you don't attach, and make sure all variables you're plotting are inside the data you're plotting?

Comment: How come `pages` is both inside and outside the `aes` call?

Comment: Wait, you may want to add `data = p` to `geom_errorbar`.

Comment: if i don't attach, i can't use 'se'. it's weird cuz i can use 'mean' even though i don't attach 'p'

Comment: i added data=p as you said, now they say they cant find 'pages' (in raw data). i will try more. thanks

Comment: so i changed 'mean+se' to 'p$mean+p$se' for ymax, and for ymin as well. and now, i got the same error : Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:p$mean - p$se, p$mean + p$se.

Comment: Are you trying to make a bar plot of the means with error bars?  In your code, it looks like you make a summary dataset for the means/se but then you make a bar plot using the raw data (`read`) instead of the mean dataset (`p`).  To plot the means instead, use the `p` dataset in `ggplot` with `y = mean` instead of `y = pages`.  Using `p` will also help with your `geom_errorbar` problem.

Comment: it works.........it was a silly question. thanks a lot